# JS function no longer applies

Tags: google-chrome-extension

**Hello everyone.**

I am currently trying to develop an extension for the Chrome browser and am having a problem.

My extension works, but the **JS** function which is integrated only works page load, or when it refresh.
But when browsing, when you return to the page or text should be amended, the ***JS*** function no longer applies: cry:

Here is an example to better explain myself;)
Function is to replace text with another text:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": [ "content.js", "init.js" ],
        "matches": [ "http://battlelog.battlefield.com/*" ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    } ],
    "name": "My Extension",
    "author" : "Tesla",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "DESCRIPTION COMING !",
    "key": "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",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "14.0"
}
```

**content.js:**

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL('main.js');
head.appendChild(script);

var css = document.createElement('link');
css.type = 'text/css';
css.rel = 'stylesheet';
css.href = chrome.extension.getURL('main.css');
head.appendChild(css);
```

**main.js:**

```
var modif = {
  change: 'Text-Change'
};

var original = {
  change: /Leaderboards/gm,
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.base-middle').each(function() {
        var $p = $(this);
        var html = $p.html();
            $p.html(html.replace(original.change, modif.change));  
    });
});
```

The function must edit the text:

***Leaderboards***

in

***Text-Change***

on this page : http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/leaderboard/

without having to refresh the page every time.

If anyone can help me?
thank you ;)
Tesla

**EDIT/** 
I posted a response after this message

Comment: The problem your having is that the page is AJAX driven.  So after the page loads and you click on one of the tabs it doesnt reload the page, but gets the contents of the new page using XMLHttpRequest and inserts it into the currently loaded page.  How to deal with this is something Im still not utterly sure on.  I was having a look at it for you, but all of a sudden that link is getting a 404.

Comment: EDIT/ I posted a response after this message

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, your dealing with an AJAX driven page which makes things rather tricky (any advice from anyone on how to deal with an ajax site would surely be appreciated).
One thing I noticed with that page is after it gets the pages contents and renders them to the page it executes `Surface.Renderer.invokeUsedComponents` so you could hijack that function and then redo your mod if window.location equals the url you want to mod on.
A quick example on how to hijack that function looks like....

```
(function(old){
Surface.Renderer.invokeUsedComponents = function(a){
    //  Check window.location and if it matches then do something
    alert(a);
    old.apply(Surface.Renderer, arguments);
}   
})(Surface.Renderer.invokeUsedComponents)
```

Be aware that I didnt do heaps of testing and if they ever change their api it could break your extension....
Good Luck!

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that your going to need to inject that code into the page and have it communicate back to the extension.
Heres some code that should work (I didnt test it, just modded some code I had already)...

```
// http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication
var comDiv = document.createElement('div');
comDiv.setAttribute("id", "stateChangeDiv");
document.documentElement.appendChild(comDiv);

script = function(old) {
    // Create the event that the content script listens for
    var stateChangeEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
    stateChangeEvent.initEvent('stateChangeEvent', true, true);

    // overide the function that gets called after the page is updated
    Surface.Renderer.invokeUsedComponents = function(a) {

        var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('stateChangeDiv');
        hiddenDiv.dispatchEvent(stateChangeEvent);
        //console.debug(c);
        old.apply(Surface.Renderer, arguments);
    }

}

function override(fn) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
    script.textContent = '(' + fn + ')(Surface.Renderer.invokeUsedComponents);';
    document.documentElement.appendChild(script); // run the script
    document.documentElement.removeChild(script); // clean up
}

override(script);

document.getElementById('stateChangeDiv').addEventListener('stateChangeEvent', function() {
// This will get executed everytime Surface.Renderer.invokeUsedComponents does on the page
    alert('page updated, check your window.location and do something');

});
```

Comment: EDIT/ I posted a response after this message